# spark-sftp not considering the single quote("\'") option. Reads single quote as as part of the value

Tags: apache-spark, spark-sftp

I have to read a csv file from sftp server into spark dataframe that has a column containing currency values like this and another column containing text values. Since the comma is a delimiter so the currency value is conatined inside the single quote.

```
'$1,200.00', abc
'$1,201.00', und
'$1,202.00', jsn
'$1,203.00', yhs
'$1,204.00', rfs
'$1,205.00', jsn
'$1,202.00', han
```

When I read this using the below code, Spark reads this as three columns whne it should read it as two.

```
val df sqlContext.read.format("com.springml.spark.sftp")
.option("quote","\'")
.option("host","mylocalhost")
.option("username","user")
.option("password","password")
.option("header", "false")
.option("fileType", "csv")
.option("delimiter", ",")
.option("inferSchema", "true")
.load("path/to/file.csv")

df:
'$1,   200.00'  abc
```

Comment: What if `.option("quote","'")`?

Comment: PS: this works absolutely fine when the quote used is is double quote

Comment: @Lamanus tried that already. No luck.

Comment: @arpit this works absolutely fine for me. Check if the file has any hidden characters or carriage returns at EOL.